# Find PowerShell-Cmdlets with no parameters

Tags: powershell, reflection

I would like to get all PowerShell-Cmdlets in the current session that have no parameters (if they are any).

When I try

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Where-Object { $_.Parameters.Count -eq 0 } | Select-Object -Property Name, @{n="PCount";e={$_.Parameters.Count}}
```

I'll get a lot of Cmdlets. But it turns out that they actually have parameters:

```
(Get-Command -Name Write-Host).Parameters.Count
```

What is the correct way to get Cmdlets that have no parameters?

Comment: `CommandInfo.Parameters` contains _common parameters_ as well (`-Verbose`, `-Debug`, `-OutVariable`, etc.), so the count will never be 0 for any cmdlet. Perhaps you're looking for cmdlets with 0 _mandatory_ parameters?

Comment: I believe what OP is stating is that he is getting wrong results, most likely due to lazy loading of the parameter info, a consecutive piping to `Get-Command` would solve this problem: `Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Command | Where-Object { $_.Parameters.Count -eq 0 }` should return no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get no results from your filter however, as you stated you're getting wrong results and this is most likely due to lazy loading of the parameter info of each command, a consecutive piping to `Get-Command` forces the cmdlets' module to be loaded then the issue is gone, using `CimCmdlets` Module as example:

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet |
    Where-Object { $_.Parameters.Count -eq 0 -and $_.ModuleName -eq 'CimCmdlets' }


CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source    
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------    
Cmdlet          Export-BinaryMiLog                                 7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-CimAssociatedInstance                          7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-CimClass                                       7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-CimInstance                                    7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-CimSession                                     7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Import-BinaryMiLog                                 7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Invoke-CimMethod                                   7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          New-CimInstance                                    7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          New-CimSession                                     7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          New-CimSessionOption                               7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Register-CimIndicationEvent                        7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Remove-CimInstance                                 7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Remove-CimSession                                  7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Set-CimInstance                                    7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets

PS ..\pwsh> Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Command |
    Where-Object { $_.Parameters.Count -eq 0 -and $_.ModuleName -eq 'CimCmdlets' }

PS ..\pwsh>
```

If you want to get all cmdlets having no parameters but excluding [`CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.commonparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) and [`OptionalCommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.optionalcommonparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-optionalcommonparameters) you could use:

```
$common = [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters
$optional = [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::OptionalCommonParameters

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Command | Where-Object {
    -not $_.Parameters.Keys.Where({ -not ($common.Contains($_) -or $optional.Contains($_)) })
}
```

Or, tip from [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), easier way using the [`CommandMetadata` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandmetadata?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) to get the commands' parameters excluding common and optional:

```bash
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Command | Where-Object {
    -not [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new($_).Parameters.Count
}
```

Comment: Easier way to count user-defined parameters only: `([System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData](Get-Command <name>)).Parameters.Count`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good point forgot about that one, thanks

Comment: Thanks to the clever type casting I was actually able to get all the cmdlets with only common parameters:
```Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Get-Command | Select-Object Name, @{n="PCount";e={([System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData]$_).Parameters.Count}} | Where-Object PCount -eq 0```